# Oracle 10g direct path write/read wait events

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle10g

My 10g oracle prod database have performance problem. Some queries begun to return in 20 seconds which was comes in milliseconds. I get AWR report and top3 wait event shown below. I searched but i couldnt understand as well.

Can someone explain this events ? Thanks,

```
Event                       Waits           Time(s)     Avg Wait(ms)    % Total Call Time   Wait Class
----------------------      ----------      -------     ------------    -----------------   ----------  
direct path write temp      11,941,557      866,004     73              29.8                User I/O      FEBRUARY
direct path write temp      16,197,445      957,129     59              17.2                User I/O      MARCH

db file scattered read      5,826,190       58,095      10              2.0                 User I/O      FEBRUARY
db file scattered read      10,128,657      70,408      7               1.3                 User I/O      MARCH

direct path read temp       34,197,762      324,663     9               11.2                User I/O      FEBRUARY
direct path read temp       88,688,686      507,715     6               9.1                 User I/O      MARCH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of your wait events are related to sorting: `direct path write temp` and `direct path read temp`. These indicate an increase in sorting on disk rather than in memory; disk I/O is always slower.

So, what has changed regarding memory allocation usage?  Perhaps you need to revisit the values of SORT_AREA_SIZE or PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET init parameters (depending on whether you are using Automatic PGA memory). Here is a query which calculates the memory/disk sort ratio:

```
SELECT 100 * (mem.value - dsk.value)/(mem.value) AS sort_ratio 
FROM v$sysstat mem
     cross join v$sysstat dsk 
WHERE mem.name = 'sorts (memory)' 
AND dsk.name ='sorts (disk)'
```

In an OLTP application we would expect this to be over 95%.

The other thing is, instead of looking at macro events you need to look at the specific queries which are running much slower. What has changed with regards to them? Lots more data? New indexes or dropped indexes? Refreshed statistics?

---

> "SORT_RATIO ---------- 99.9985462"

So, sorts are higher but not too high. You need to focus on specific queries.

> "in march we begun to user phyton application for some new queries. reason can be this ? "

Could be. Application change is always the prime suspect when our system exhibits different behavior.

Comment: nothing has changed. no any new or deleted index. but in march we begun to user phyton application for some new queries. reason can be this ?

Comment: and one more segment by logical read part has inluding new and so big values. Should i understand new queries begun on database and this queries reason for this ?

Comment: SORT_RATIO
----------
99.9985462